# compile stylus sheets to a single file

Tags: shell, stylus

I am trying to write a watch script for my app. I have a stylus sheet for each feature of my app and I'd like to compile them into a single one.

```
stylus -u nib src/*/*/**.styl -o out/css/ --include-css -w
```

But this brings as many files as there are features. Is there a way to ensure that each newly compiled css file is appended to my `out/css/main.css` file rather than written as a new `out/css/feature.css` file?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import all the features in one file (`main.styl`) and watch only it (`stylus -w main.styl`), isn't it? Any changes to these files will be detected by Stylus and `main.styl` file will be recompiled as well. There is a reason why you don't do it this way?